# Run parallel process dynamically

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have watcher script, which runs a sqlplus statement to fetch what are files are ready for processing. Once I get the list (FileList.txt), I use this file in a while statement to call a java command which processes the files one by one.

Once the while statement is completed, it will fetch another set of files from Sqlplus and the same process continue till all the files are completed.

I need to run that java command in parallel instead of sequentially in the same script.

FileList.txt

```
QWE
ASD
ZXV
POI
LKJ
MNB
```

Java command which is getting in script. Here $FILENAME is fetched from FileList.txt

```bash
java -Dspring.config.location=/config/application.properties -Dlogging.config=/config/logback-spring.xml -Dlho.logdir=$LOG -jar $JARPATH  --fileName=$FILENAME
```

Comment: GNU parallel is your friend.

Comment: `parallel -j 2 Child.sh '{}' :::: FileList.CSV` iirc

Comment: If you are attempting to convince us that this isn't a duplicate, what happened when you tried the answers from the duplicate? (Please don't respond in comments; then we have to post another comment to tell you to delete the comment and repeat the request to [edit] the question instead.)

Answer (score 0):

First create a sample `child.sh` that can take a variable time for processing

```
#!/bin/bash
((delay=RANDOM%3 +1))
echo "Processing $1 over $delay seconds"
sleep $delay
echo "Processed $1"
```

Next use the `xargs` function with `-P 2` (two parallel executions):

```
cat FileList.CSV | xargs -n1 -P2 ./child.sh
```

Sample output, I manually added `(1)` and `(2)`

```
(1) Processing QWE over 3 seconds
(2) Processing ASD over 1 seconds
(2) Processed ASD
(2) Processing ZXV over 1 seconds
(2) Processed ZXV
(2) Processing POI over 2 seconds
(1) Processed QWE
(1) Processing LKJ over 3 seconds
(2) Processed POI
(2) Processing MNB over 1 seconds
(2) Processed MNB
(1) Processed LKJ
```

When you want to see your prompt after the last child finished, add a `wait`:

```
cat FileList.CSV | xargs -n1 -P2 ./child.sh& wait
```